# Invalidate Output cache and IIS

Tags: c#, iis, outputcache

I have a small example of output cache, I build a project with an action

```
[OutputCache (Duration=3600,VaryByParam="file")]
public string Up(string file)
{
}
```

that load mp4 video and another one remove output cache

```
public string Down(string file)
{
    HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(file);
}
```

and attached it with w3p process ( IIS 7). 
My problem is first time when the action loaded, a video being cached in IIS (w3p process RAM from 100 -> 400MB). After that, I call the invalidate action to remove output cache but RAM of w3p process doesn't return to 100.
I tried to turn off cache, kernel cache of IIS but nothing change. Can you guys show me where am I wrong ?
Thanks